# How to use external sonar server for jHipster project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I am currently developing a spring boot application with jHipster and I want to use an existing sonar server from my company to analyze the code. JHipster only describes a way to use a build in sonar server from a docker container. Unfortunately that is not an option for me since my machine is running on Windows Server 2012, that is not supported by docker.
I already tried to start the maven build by adding the server url as a build parameter to the maven build, but it is ignoring it.

```
mvn clean test sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://server-ip:server-port/ -Dsonar.login=login -Dsonar.password=pw
```

I am relatively new to the topic and was using the given command by the jhipster reference page (https://jhipster.github.io/code-quality/), so the test profile should be the correct one for this purpose.
When I run the command it ignores the given url paramter and still tries to use localhost where it expects the sonar in a docker container.

```
08:31:53.473 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for 
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.017 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-12T08:31:53+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/392M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project project: Fail to connect to database: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.Driver' -> [
Help 1]
```

Since jHipster generates and configures a lot in the background I have no idea if I am missing something vital here. Maybe a configuration file I have to adjust? I really appreciate the help.

The pom.xml was generated by jHipster and the maven plugin is configured as followed:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
 </plugin>
```

The version is set in the properties as:

```
<sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.2</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
```

I tried setting up my project on a linux vm with a running local docker sonar instance as suggested by the jHipster team and it was running fine, it is just very inconvenient for me since I have an available company sonar instance running in the intranet.

I also tried modifying my settings.xml as suggested and that was ignored, though it lead to a different looking error message:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) @ project ---
[INFO] User cache: C:\Users\Administrator\.sonar\cache
[ERROR] SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-14T11:29:22+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 57M/408M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project project: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server: Status r
eturned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/index] is not valid: [404] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Show how you configured your sonar maven plugin. http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: I added the configuration to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained in the sonar docs : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven

You should edit the settings.xml file in you `~/.m2`directory with the following:

```
<settings>
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                  http://myserver:9000
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
     </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I tried modifying the settings.xml file as suggested, though it is still trying to access the sonar instance at localhost and ignores the changes. Only the error message changed. I edited the original post to show the other error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line into the properties section of your pom.xml file.

```
<sonar.host.url>http://1.2.3.4:9000/</sonar.host.url>
```

With the IP address corresponding to your sonarqube server.